# Jmeter load distribution using single thread group

Tags: jmeter, controller, transactions, load

I have a single thread group for 100 users and I need to distribute the load as below 100 users will navigate to login>> homepage.  After that 60 users navigate to buy shoes and the remaining 40 users will check their balance and 100 users log out. How can we achieve this in JMeter?

I am trying If controller to achieve this but cannot do so.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller), it allows you to specify either percentage or exact number of executions of its children.

[image]

If you will have more distribution options [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/weighted-switch-controller-jmeter) might be a more convenient option:

[image]

The Weighted Switch Controller can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)